# Nested components & styles in fluent ui v9 / Griffel

Tags: css, fluent-ui, fluentui-react, css-in-js, griffel.js

I have a style for a standard list

```
export const useOverrides = makeStyles({
    list: {
        ...shorthands.padding("2px", "4px", "8px", "30px"),
    },
```

I add it to the list

```
 <ul className={list}>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item1</li>
     <li>item1</li>
</ul>
```

How do I select the li component or any children using normal scss creating the style would be simple.

```
ul {
 padding: 20px;
 
li {
  color: red
}
}
```

Can I not target child selectors in this way with griffel?

```
list: {
    ...shorthands.padding("2px", "4px", "8px", "30px"),
    li: {
        color: "red",
    },
},
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `&` as reference to the current element:

```js
list: {
    ...shorthands.padding("2px", "4px", "8px", "30px"),
    '& li': {
        color: "red",
    },
    // or even more specific:
    '& > li': {
        color: "red",
    },
},
```

You can see and try it out yourself here: https://griffel.js.org/try-it-out#nested